# Is it possible to combine two movie files into one, interleaved like a zipper using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editor, video-streaming

imagine you have two movie clips, each one has the same fps and geometry and total number of pics,now take the first pic of the first clip and place the first pic of the second clip after it, than again the second pic of the first clip and so on ...

Would it be possible to create such a clip out of two others using ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

Well, not with ffmpeg alone. You would need something to render the transition from clip1 to clip 2.
I've checked out this tool (based on ffmpeg) which might come close to what you want: 
[ffpeg-concat](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/ffmpeg-concat)

But it takes some time, since the clips are rendered into scenes and put together again using ffmpeg and openGL for the transitions

Answer (score 0):

The ffmpeg concat function is for splicing a list of film sections together. I don't think the interleaving is a function that ffmpeg is set up to do. I did exactly what you describe in matlab to create an interleaved movie. I then put a soundtrack on it with ffmpeg.